# How to control the speed in Manipulation

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate

As the title says, I want to control the speed when I use `Manipulate`. I have the following piece of code

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Manipulate[
V = -(M/Sqrt[b^2 + x^2 + λ*y^2 + (a + Sqrt[h^2 + z^2])^2]);
Vxx = D[V, {x, 2}];
Vyy = D[V, {y, 2}];
Vzz = D[V, {z, 2}];
ρ = 2.325/(4*π*100)*(Vxx + Vyy + Vzz);
ρxy = ρ /. {z -> 0};
ρxz = ρ /. {y -> 0};
ρyz = ρ /. {x -> 0};

M = 9500; a = 3; h = 0.15; λ = 1.1;

Syz = ContourPlot[ρyz, {y, -30, 30}, {z, -30, 30}, Contours -> 20, 
ContourStyle -> Black, PlotPoints -> 50, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{y, z}, ρyz < 0], 
PerformanceGoal :> "Speed"],
{b, 0, 10, 0.1}]
```

My problem is that when I evaluate this in order to see what happens when the value of b changes the contours are plotted too fast without any order. Let me be more specific, the slider corresponding to b changes very fast and at any time it shows contours for completely random values of b. What I want, is to start the "animation" and be able to see in smooth and slow motion all the situations from b=0 up up b=10 using step 0.1

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
plots = Table[
V = -(M/Sqrt[b^2 + x^2 + λ*y^2 + (a + Sqrt[h^2 + z^2])^2]);
Vxx = D[V, {x, 2}]; Vyy = D[V, {y, 2}]; Vzz = D[V, {z, 2}];
ρ = (2.325/(4*Pi*100))*(Vxx + Vyy + Vzz);
ρxy = ρ /. {z -> 0};
ρxz = ρ /. {y -> 0};
ρyz = ρ /. {x -> 0};
M = 9500; a = 3; h = 0.15; λ = 1.1;
ContourPlot[ρyz, {y, -50, 50}, {z, -50, 50}, Contours -> 20, 
ContourStyle -> Black, PlotPoints -> 50, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{y, z}, ρyz < 0], 
PerformanceGoal :> "Speed", FrameLabel -> {"y", "z"}, 
RotateLabel -> False, 
FrameStyle -> 
 Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
PlotLabel -> Row[{"b = ", b}], 
LabelStyle -> 
 Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
ImageSize -> 550], {b, 0, 10, 0.1}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using `ListAnimate` as Sjoerd recommended:

```
plots = Table[
 V = -(M/Sqrt[b^2 + x^2 + λ*y^2 + (a + Sqrt[h^2 + z^2])^2]);
 Vxx = D[V, {x, 2}]; Vyy = D[V, {y, 2}]; Vzz = D[V, {z, 2}];
 ρ = (2.325/(4*Pi*100))*(Vxx + Vyy + Vzz);
 ρxy = ρ /. {z -> 0};
 ρxz = ρ /. {y -> 0};
 ρyz = ρ /. {x -> 0};
 M = 9500; a = 3; h = 0.15; λ = 1.1;
 ContourPlot[ρyz, {y, -30, 30}, {z, -30, 30}, Contours -> 20,
   ContourStyle -> Black, PlotPoints -> 50,
   RegionFunction -> Function[{y, z}, ρyz < 0],
   PerformanceGoal :> "Speed",
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"b = ", b}]
 ],
 {b, 0, 10, 0.1}
];

ListAnimate[plots, 10, DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The second argument controls the display speed of the pre-rendered frames.

Comment: Good again! But currently you have no idea what is the value of b at every time. Is there a way to add a `PlotLabel` like b = i where i is the value of b?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, Yes.  I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: One more thing! I tried to export this as an .avi file but it is way to heavy. So, is it possible to be exported as a .gif using all the intermediate steps of b?

Comment: Just Export["Animation.gif", plots] will do the job right?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Yes, it should.  If you have any problems let me know.  You may also wish to search the site for other questions about GIF export.

Comment: Yes Export works fine. I added a few additional options to the code and I noticed that even though I declare specific options regarding the fonts of the label the b = b label is not affected. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Did you try using `Style` directly?

Comment: See my EDIT. I want to modify the font size and the font family of the `PlotLabel` but I do not know why it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z It should work if you use `Style` directly, like this: `PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"b = ", b}], FontSize -> 22, Red, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]`

Comment: Yes indeed. Now it's working fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Vaggelis You're welcome.  Did you just un-vote for my answer?  I got a -10 notice.  If you already voted earlier and tried to vote again that would happen.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z You didn't need to do that.  I was just surprised to see an "un-upvote" and I wondered if it was a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the `Manipulate` for `Animate` and add the option `DisplayAllSteps->True` to, well, display all steps.

If you want to have a quality animation you could change the `Animate` to a `ListAnimate` with a `Table` generating all the plots at a higher quality setting (`PerformanceGoal :> "Quality"`)

---

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ListAnimate[
 V = -(M/Sqrt[b^2 + x^2 + \[Lambda]*y^2 + (a + Sqrt[h^2 + z^2])^2]);
 Table[
  Vxx = D[V, {x, 2}];
  Vyy = D[V, {y, 2}];
  Vzz = D[V, {z, 2}];
  \[Rho] = 2.325/(4*\[Pi]*100)*(Vxx + Vyy + Vzz);
  \[Rho]xy = \[Rho] /. {z -> 0};
  \[Rho]xz = \[Rho] /. {y -> 0};
  \[Rho]yz = \[Rho] /. {x -> 0};
  M = 9500; a = 3; h = 0.15; \[Lambda] = 1.1;
  Syz = ContourPlot[\[Rho]yz, {y, -30, 30}, {z, -30, 30}, 
    Contours -> 20, ContourStyle -> Black, PlotPoints -> 20, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{y, z}, \[Rho]yz < 0], 
    PerformanceGoal :> "Speed", 
    Epilog -> 
     Inset[Graphics@Text[b, BaseStyle -> {16, Bold}], Scaled[{0.5, 0.95}]]], {b, 0, 10, 0.1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very good! However, when I use `Animate` how can I see at any time the exact value of b?

Comment: `ListAnimate` seems more efficient way. Could you post a simple example on how it could be used in my case?

Answer (score 4):

Just to add a little to the other two solutions:  You might want to be able to compare the function values (of `ρyz`) as the graphs morph.  To do that , one can control the contour lines and the contour shading.  I chose a logarithmic scale for the contours `cntrs`, but I left the contour shading linear.  The colors have no intrinsic meaning, so it's a question of adjusting it to what looks good.

```
Clear[b];
cntrs = Union@Flatten[Transpose@{-{0., 1., 2., 5.}}.{10^Range[-5, -3]}];
plots = Module[{V, M, Vxx, Vyy, Vzz, λ, h, a, ρ, ρxy, ρxz, ρyz},
   M = 9500; a = 3; h = 0.15; λ = 1.1;
   V = -(M/
       Sqrt[b^2 + x^2 + λ*y^2 + (a + Sqrt[h^2 + z^2])^2]);
   Vxx = D[V, {x, 2}]; Vyy = D[V, {y, 2}];  Vzz = D[V, {z, 2}];
   ρ = 2.325/(4*π*100)*(Vxx + Vyy + Vzz);
   ρxy = ρ /. {z -> 0};
   ρxz = ρ /. {y -> 0};
   ρyz = ρ /. {x -> 0};
   Table[
    ContourPlot[ρyz, {y, -30, 30}, {z, -30, 30}, 
     Contours -> cntrs, ContourStyle -> Black, 
     ColorFunction -> (ColorData["DeepSeaColors"][Rescale[#, {-0.0006, 0}]] &),
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     PlotPoints -> 50, RegionFunction -> Function[{y, z}, ρyz < 0.], 
     PerformanceGoal :> "Speed", PlotRange -> {-0.1, 0.0000001}, 
     PlotLabel -> Row[{"b = ", b}]],
    {b, 0, 10, 0.1}]
   ];
```

Then either

```
ListAnimate[plots, 10]
```

or

```
Manipulate[plots[[i]], {i, 1, Length[plots], 1, AnimationRate -> 10}]
```

`ListAnimate` is better, I believe, but you did ask about `Manipulate`.

[image: Animation of plots]